# Why are there significantly different performance results using openssl speed when using -aead and not using it?

Tags: openssl

If I take the following two commands, the results between the two are incredibly different:

`openssl speed -aead -evp AES-128-CBC-HMAC-SHA256 -seconds 30`

`openssl speed -evp AES-128-CBC-HMAC-SHA256 -seconds 30`

The results for the first look like:

```
   2 bytes      31 bytes      136 bytes     1024 bytes     8192 bytes     16384 bytes
26,614.91k   362,373.52k  1,547,884.13k 11,946,116.73k 94,651,093.34k 189,574,719.91k
```

And the results for the second look like:

```
  16 bytes       64 bytes      256 bytes     1024 bytes     8192 bytes    16384 bytes
438,548.92k   894,497.63k  1,337,354.57k  1,581,342.47k  1,650,846.18k  1,655,817.68k
```

I'm not talking about the slightly different block sizes. After you get into the 1,024 block size, the performance is incredibly different. Why?

Comment: Please provide version of openssl, or if it's actually LibreSSL shipped by Apple or something. And also provide the CPU you're benchmarking on.

Comment: On my openssl 1.1.1f and 3.2.2-dev, `openssl speed -aead -evp AES-128-CBC-HMAC-SHA256` doesn't work. I guess because it's not an AEAD. For `AES-128-GCM` and `CHACHA20-POLY1305` both work and produce expected results (with `-aead` the 16k speed is a little slower than without `-aead`). This is on an older x86 laptop with Ubuntu 20.04.